# "Interesting Questions" page bug?

Tags: support, interesting-page

Look here - it's a list of new things that match my tags, so what is the 4k views, already answered and accepted question doing there? Is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: No, it is not "new things".  It is the interesting tab, which has new and old questions with recent activity.